# What do the values in 'alsa --dump-hw-params' represent?

Tags: alsa

I am having problems configuring ALSA on my RHEL 7.5 machine.

Part of my solution is to attempt to change settings in /etc/asound.conf.  I have tried numerous permutations but I continue to hear "jitter" in my sounds (.raw files).

I am using the 'aplay --dump-hw-params  to get the params for my sound HW.

Using this command:

```
aplay --dump-hw-params Front_Center.wav
```

These are the results I get:

```
Playing WAVE 'Front_Center.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Mono
HW Params of device "default":
--------------------
ACCESS:  MMAP_INTERLEAVED MMAP_NONINTERLEAVED MMAP_COMPLEX RW_INTERLEAVED RW_NONINTERLEAVED
```

FORMAT:  S8 U8 S16_LE S16_BE U16_LE U16_BE S24_LE S24_BE U24_LE U24_BE S32_LE S32_BE U32_LE U32_BE FLOAT_LE FLOAT_BE FLOAT64_LE FLOAT64_BE MU_LAW A_LAW IMA_ADPCM S24_3LE S24_3BE U24_3LE U24_3BE S20_3LE S20_3BE U20_3LE U20_3BE S18_3LE S18_3BE U18_3LE U18_3BE

```
SUBFORMAT:  STD
SAMPLE_BITS: [4 64]
FRAME_BITS: [4 640000]
CHANNELS: [1 10000]
RATE: [4000 4294967295)
PERIOD_TIME: (11609 11610)
PERIOD_SIZE: (46 49864571)
PERIOD_BYTES: (23 4294967295)
PERIODS: (0 17344165)
BUFFER_TIME: [1 4294967295]
BUFFER_SIZE: [92 797831566]
BUFFER_BYTES: [46 4294967295]
TICK_TIME: ALL
--------------------
```

I'd like to know what the values within parens and braces mean in general.
Are they ranges?
What is the difference between the use of parens vs. braces?

Thanks,
Ian

Answer (score 1):

Minimum and maximum values as supported by the specific hardware device you are using.

Comment: What is the difference between the use of parens vs. braces? Was not answered.